# Create grouped pie chart from user input R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, aggregate

I want the user to be able to upload a .csv and be able to create a pie chart of it. If there is a column that contains a category they want grouped together they should be able to.
The following code shows what I want to do, but only works if I know the column name (in this case Gender) when writing the program.

```
piePlotData = aggregate(. ~ Gender, inFile, sum)
pie(piePlotData[[input$pieData]], labels = piePlotData[[input$pieGroups]])
```

If possible I would want to replace Gender with `input$pieGroups`

Here is a simple example of data which could be uploaded:

```
  Gender    Name    Maths   English 
   M        Bob      4        2 
   M        Fred     1        7
   F        Mary     5        4
```

I apologise if this has been answered before, I have tried other people's solutions but I could not get them to work when the data uploaded could be in any format and still keeping the same column names.

I'd prefer if the solution only used the base R package, but any solutions are better than none :P
Thanks in advance

(Somewhat) Simple code example:

server.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  inFile = reactive({ return (read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE))})

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "pieData", choices = names(inFile()))
    updateSelectInput(session, "pieGroups", choices = names(inFile()))
  })

  output$plot = renderPlot({
    piePlotData = aggregate(. ~ Gender, inFile, sum)
    pie(piePlotData[[input$pieData]], labels = piePlotData[[input$pieGroups]])
  })
})
```

ui.R:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Grouped Pie Chart"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("pieData", "Columns in pie", "Update"),
    selectInput("pieGroups", "Groups for pie", "Update")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
))
```

Comment: Try `aggregate(formula(paste0(".~",input$pieGroups)), inFile(), sum)` to make the formula out of a string. Can't test it without all the other elements of your app.

Comment: It works, thank you so much. I added example code onto my question to try to make it clearer. If you could write your comment as an answer then I can accept it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `formula` to create a formula from strings.

For example in your `server.R` you could do:

```
piePlotData = aggregate(formula(paste0(".~",input$pieGroups)), inFile(), sum)
```